# Dynamically opening a doc file c#

Tags: c#, web-applications

I have been using this line of code for the past few weeks to dynamically open a doc file once the user has created it and its been working fine...

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\" + txtEditTitle.Text + ".doc");
```

but today, for some reason it gives me the following error:

[image: This has today started appearing]

Can anybody help?

Comment: Could you open the same file using Word? And what is the exact file name?

Comment: File must have been removed. Can you check whether the file is there on the desktop ?

Comment: The file still exists?

Comment: It cannot find the file. What is the path?

Comment: You are using the verbatim string literal with `@`..  `\\\` means literally `\\\`, not a one backslash: `\\`

Comment: for some reason its working after i restarted visual studio, the document was there on the desktop

Comment: Make sure that the file is `.doc` or `.docx`

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the exception the file is not there. It would not be wrong to check if the [file exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) before opening it.

Comment: the file does exist as its there on the desktop, i closed down visual studio and re opened and it seems to be working now?

Comment: Could it be that the file was opened by other process?

Comment: dont think so, this is the only page and only time i use the process.start command

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshot, it shows file is not there. Check your path for the file and make sure file exists:

```
string  strPath = "C:\\Users\\peter\\Desktop\\" + txtEditTitle.Text + ".doc";
// strPath=@"C:\Users\peter\Desktop\" + txtEditTitle.Text + ".doc";
if (File.Exists(strPath))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(strPath);
}
```